# How to get the coordinates of a sliced volume?

Tags: python, coordinates

I have a project where I need to calculate the immersed volume of a floating body (e.g., ship).

I am starting with the basics, so I am considering a cube for now. The waterline is assumed to be a plane.

In the photo, the cube is cut through by a plane, so Is it possible to get the coordinates of the shape beneath the plane into a python code? and how can it be done?
[image]

This will be the immersed volume of the cube in water.

Comment: you use a boolean modifier and then you can ask python for the resulting coordinates? And since you hopefully have experience with python you should know how to ask for coordinates...

Answer (score 5):

**Bisect at waterline.**

Making  the assumption that the water is an infinite plane, defined by location and normal of a plane object, default aligned such that its local Z axis designates "above water".. *another option would be to  define the plane, *eg*  XY plane, and position vessel in relation to it. location `(0, 0, 0)` normal `(0, 0, 1)`*.

Test script.

- Water object is named "Plane"
- Select context object and run script. The context object is the "vessel"
- Using `bmesh.from_object` loads the evaluated (modified) mesh into a bmesh
- Transform the bmesh to put into global coordinates.
- Use the global coordinate and global z axis of water object to define our water level
- Get the volume of whole vessel,
- Bisect with clear outer will leave just that below the water level.

Test script.

```
import bpy
import bmesh

context = bpy.context

water = bpy.data.objects.get("Plane")
vessel = context.object

bm = bmesh.new()
dg = context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()

bm.from_object(vessel, dg)
bm.transform(vessel.matrix_world)

print(f"Total Volume : {bm.calc_volume()}")
geom = bmesh.ops.bisect_plane(
        bm,
        geom=bm.faces[:] + bm.edges[:] + bm.verts[:],
        plane_no=water.matrix_world.col[2].xyz,
        plane_co=water.matrix_world.translation,
        clear_outer=True, # clear above water
        )
#print(geom) # contains geom of cut
#bm now only has cut and the remaining geometry that is below water level.
print("#Verts")
for v in bm.verts:
    print(f"{v.co[:]}")
print("#Faces")
for f in bm.faces:
    print([v.index for v in f.verts])
#bm.normal_update()
#bm.to_mesh(bpy.data.meshes.new(f"{vessel.data.name} BWL")) # to test mesh result 
print(f"Below water : {bm.calc_volume()}")
```

Result on test cube sliced by default plane.

```
Total Volume : 7.999999999999999
Below water : 3.9999999999999996
```

Note, haven't overly tested this. Depending on the volume calculation may need to fill post bisection.

Comment: thanks a lot! I will test the code and let you know.

Comment: By the way, How is it possible to get the coordinates of the lower part?

Comment: Edited to print them to system console.

Answer (score 4):

This script below will print out the upper and lower volumes of the immersed object.

For instance for this object (default cube):
[image]

The results are:

```
5.715525159648066 2.2844748412617073
```

This is of course in Blender units.

```
import bpy
import bmesh

immersed_obj = bpy.data.objects['Cube']
water_obj    = bpy.data.objects['Plane']

# add the modifier and change settings

m = immersed_obj.modifiers.get('Boolean')
if m is None:
    m           = immersed_obj.modifiers.new(name = "Boolean", type = 'BOOLEAN')
    m.object    = water_obj

S = bpy.context.scene

# Upper part (assuming water object normals are facing up)
m.operation = "DIFFERENCE" 
depsgraph   = bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()
bm_upper    = bmesh.new()

immersed_obj = immersed_obj.evaluated_get(depsgraph)
bm_upper.from_mesh( immersed_obj.to_mesh(preserve_all_data_layers=True, depsgraph=depsgraph) )

# Lower part (same assumption)
m.operation  = "INTERSECT"
bm_lower     = bmesh.new()
depsgraph    = bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()
immersed_obj = immersed_obj.evaluated_get(depsgraph)
bm_lower.from_mesh( immersed_obj.to_mesh(preserve_all_data_layers=True, depsgraph=depsgraph) )

upper_vol = bm_upper.calc_volume()
lower_vol = bm_lower.calc_volume()
print( upper_vol, lower_vol )
```

Comment: thanks a lot! I will test the code and let you know.

Comment: By the way, How is it possible to get the coordinates of the lower part?

Comment: Essentially, you have the bmesh object of the lower part, called `bm_lower`. You can access its vertices and other mesh elements via the `bm_lower.verts` / `bm.lower.edges` / `bm_lower.faces` collections.